# By scapy, update packet TCP Sequence and Acknowledge number and IP layer length automatically when packet edited manually

Tags: python, network-programming, scapy, packet, packet-capture

I am reading the packets from a pcap file and inserting some unique id in the TCP payload, So the IP layer length and TCP Sequence and Acknowledge number need to update. Is it possible to do this by scapy?

```
for pkt in pkt_reader_pcap:

    if IP not in pkt:
        continue

    if TCP not in pkt:
        continue

    newp = pkt.payload
    newp[IP].dst = 1.2.3.4
    newp[IP].src = 1.2.3.4
    del newp[IP].len
    del newp[IP].chksum

    # if pkt has TCP layer, insert field before Host to the payload
    field = "Id: 1234\r\n"

    insert = field + 'Host: '
    http_content = newp.getlayer(Raw).load
    http_content = http_content.replace(b"Host: ", insert.encode())
    newp[Raw].load = http_content
    newp[TCP].chksum = None

    ## manually updated length of IP header which works fine, but it should happen 
    ## automatically or by some method of scapy
    newp[IP].len += len(field)
```

I set the TCP/IP checksum to None, but still, the Seq/Ack number is not updated. Is there any way to achieve the same?

Comment: How would the seq ack be updated ? When ?

Comment: @Cukic0d is pointing you in the right direction. I would read up on how TCP works with SEQ/ACK numbers as that will help you. Take a look at Packetlife's treatment of this: https://packetlife.net/blog/2010/jun/7/understanding-tcp-sequence-acknowledgment-numbers/

Comment: @Cukic0d, As when we insert data into a TCP stream, old seq# and ACK# are no longer correct.

Comment: @RossJacobs, Thank you for sharing the link. It is very informative.

Comment: Judging from your comment above this one, you should actually read it.